# Ignore other inputs while code is being executed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Does any1 know how to make this code --> To prevent and ignore any other inputs for over 2 seconds after it is being executed? It's seems a very easy question, but l'm been struggling for 2 days googling for this, pls help.

```
public void PressCOM(string key)
{
    if (key == "P")
    {
        PressP("p");
        ReleaseKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); not do what you need?

Comment: `Sleep` only delays the input, it do not ignore user's input...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know when `PressCOM` is called, or what `PressP` and `ReleaseKey` do, so I might be off. However, if `PressCOM` is called as an event when a key is pressed, why don't you create your own blackout period, during which you won't handle any futher events?

Comment: Actually this is a code for touchpad virtual keyboard. But the code they are using is strange to me. So l do not know how to modify the function into something similar to Buttons. The `PressCOM` the virtual pad, and `PressP` is an image to be touch by user.

Answer (score 2):

If this code is called during an event handler method, you can:

1) Disable the event handler method on enter and reenable on exit

```
myCtrl.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(myHandler);  
PressCom(key);  
myCtrl.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(myHandler);
```

2) or simply declare a static global form variable and inside your KeyPress event

```
private static _onKeyPress = false;  

if(_onKeyPress == false)   
{  
    _onKeyPress = true;  
    PressCom(key);  
    _onKeyPress = false;  
}
```

in each case, it is necessary to add, to the pseudocode presented here, an appropriate handling of error conditions. Otherwise, you could end in a state in which no event handler is wired to your keypress or a global variable is set to true and none can reset it to false.